# Moving the Character Accordingly to the Tiles

Tags: c#, xna

On my previous post I was mentioning studying C# with the XNA library in my free time, it’s always the case; however, I have been stuck for long hours on something I have troubles to figure out in the logic!

Here is a resume of the current situation, actually my character moves 2 per 2 pixels, this value is stored in a variable I’ve called “speed” in **Player.cs** :

```
private Texture2D texture;
private Vector2 position, previousPosition;
private Rectangle sourceRect;
private KeyboardState currentInput, previousInput;

private int currentFrame = 0, frameLine = 0;
private float speed = 2f, elapsedTime, animationTime = 128f;
```

(My Inputs are ZQSD for Azerty Keyboards by the way ;D)

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    currentInput = Keyboard.GetState();

    if (currentInput.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
    {
        if (!Map.isColliding(position.X, position.Y - speed))
            position.Y -= speed;

        this.Animate(gameTime, 3);
    }
    else if (currentInput.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
    {
        if (!Map.isColliding(position.X - speed, position.Y))
            position.X -= speed;

        this.Animate(gameTime, 1);
    }
    else
        sourceRect = new Rectangle(32, (32 * frameLine), 32, 32);

    previousInput = currentInput;
}

public void Animate(GameTime gameTime, int m_frameLine)
{
    elapsedTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    frameLine = m_frameLine;

    if (elapsedTime > animationTime)
    {
        if (currentFrame >= 2)
            currentFrame = 0;
        else
            currentFrame++;

        elapsedTime = 0;
    }

    sourceRect = new Rectangle((32 * currentFrame), (32 * frameLine), 32, 32);
}
```

**Map.cs** builds the entire map with a Tile set, of course since I had difficulty to find out a “good” logic, I’ve been watching tutorials on YouTube, so here is the result anyway :

[MAP PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eiGa.png)

Now I can explain where I’m going with this!
I can move through the map normally, the collision works, but when the character wants to go between two collision tiles (between walls for example), it won’t work if there is one single pixel too much left or right (or up and down, depends on the direction) :

This is because the character’s **speed is two pixels at a time**, and sometimes (mostly always) it’s kinda tricky to get him perfectly in the middle to go through the passage.

So my question is, how could I handle the displacement of the player so that he **keeps the speed, but only stop every 32 pixels and so on** for example? I’ve been trying so many possibilities that it’s not funny anymore, I’m in a logic stuck, I’m certain to look at the wrong way, uselessly…

If anyone could enlighten me with this situation, where to begin or what to modify, I would really appreciate, also, thank you for reading me!!

Comment: The object is being moved from tile to tile? i mean, the object moves (speed * time) on each frame you detect the keys on down state or when you detect a key press and the object is not moving you fire an Animation from current tile to next tile? maybe you can add the Animate function code...

Comment: Yes I think you see my point ! I would globally like a tile to tile displacement, with a specified speed :) The animation code has been added!

Comment: From my point of view, your animation is flawed... if you want to move from A to B you need some animation class which has the start and end positions, the start time and duration, if your object is animating don't fire any other animations for the object. Then I would have a list of Animations and on the Update phase i would Update the animation returning a true or false, true meaning the animation has finished, in this case the animation will travel from A to B exactly. And to ensure the end position I would use a Lerp(start, end, Math.Min((currentTime - startTime) / animationLength, 1).

Comment: Also, I would not check if the object is colliding but if it will collide, you are using a tile system so you know if it will be colliding if you move it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I shall work on the animation class as soon as possible then, it's all kinda new to me, I hope to be in a position to fulfill this task haha!

Comment: Just don't get scared for all the maths, its a lot funnier than it seems, I love to program these kind of things (game engines) :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly your question, you should calculate your designated future position based on actual position of your player and then move toward its future position. In different words: your player have position stored in Vector2. So you need to calculate your next position based on where you want to move. So if you want to move right, calculate actual_position + new Vector2(32,0), for left you need actual_position + new Vector2(-32,0), for top actual_position + new Vector2(0,32), for bot actual_position + new Vector2(0,-32). Then just apply speed and if player reach calculated vector, just stop movement

Comment: Yes, I see your point! Thank you I'm going to try this then, and about my question, as I said in the comments above, I would like to have a tile to tile displacement, with a specified speed, since English is not my primary language, I try to be accurate as best I can :]